# mongodb - query documents by value of field name

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Given I have these documents in `User` collection:

```
{
  userId: "user-a",
  points: {
    date: {
      1: 100,
      5: 20,
      11: 65,
    },
  },
}

{
  userId: "user-b",
  points: {
    date: {
      31: 20,
      25: 40,
      11: 15,
    },
  },
}
```

What I want to do is I want to query users with `points.date.[number]` value exist and `[number]` < 7 for example. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Since your keys are unknown you have to convert them to some key value pair using [**`$objectToArray`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/) aggregation and then can easily [**`$match`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) with it

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "points.date[number]": { "$exists": true }}},
  { "$addFields": {
    "match": {
      "$objectToArray": "$points.date"
    }
  }},
  { "$match": { "match.k": { "$lt": "7" }}},
  { "$project": { "match": 0 }}
])
```

Comment: hi, I tried using your query but it returns an empty array. I tried `points.date` instead of `points.date[number]` then it has some results but in the returned documents, points.date.(number) always have `(number) > 7` (doesn't match the condition that `number` should be less than 7)

Comment: Could you explain bit more